# Codeigniter "Query was empty" error when importing .sql file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm doing an import function for .sql files. I tried following the steps given in this link http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/151225/#733423 but I keep getting the "Query was empty" error.

This is my code:

// I'm moving the uploaded file to a folder named 'path' and try to load it there.

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$file_path = './path/';

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file_path.$file);

$file = $this->load->file($file_path.$file, true);

$file_array = explode(';', $file);

foreach($file_array as $query) {

$this->db->query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0");
$this->db->query($query);
$this->db->query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1");

}
```

After executing the function, I get the error but the data were successfully inserted to the database. I can't seem to find what's wrong here. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last value of `$file_array` maybe empty, so you should do like this:

```
foreach($file_array as $query) {
    if (!empty(trim($query))){
        $this->db->query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0");
        $this->db->query($query);
        $this->db->query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried it but still no luck.

Comment: change a little, have a try.

Comment: The line if (!empty(trim($query))) gave me a bit of error so I changed it to: 

$str = trim($query)

if (!empty($str)) {
}

And now it works! I can't believe it is just this simple. Thank you very much!